# Issue with making transaction in Neo4J Python

Tags: python, transactions, neo4j

I am trying to send a POST request with a Neo4j transaction query. Although I get a response 200 the node is not created. This is my Python script:

```
import requests
import json
import csv

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit"



checkNode = {"query" : '{"statements": [{"statement":"CREATE (n:test) RETURN n"}]}'}
mkr =requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(checkNode), headers=headers)

print(mkr)
```

I haven't used transactions before and nver tried to create one through the Rest Api. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely to me that you're receiving a response code of 200; you should be getting a 500 as [the transactional endpoint doesn't accept a `query` parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request). Try this:

```
import requests
import json
import csv

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit"

checkNode = {"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE n RETURN n"}]}
mkr = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(checkNode), headers=headers)

print(mkr.text)
```